# Duplicating Rows by creating unique columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Have a situation where

```
one    two    three    type 
x      x               chocolate
x                      vanilla 
x      x               strawberry
```

if I wanted to duplicate based on the 'x's within the columns, so for instance:

```
one    two    three    type 
x                      chocolate
       x               chocolate
x                      vanilla 
x                      strawberry
       x               strawberry
```

The goal here is to have one 'x' in each row, so duplicate the whole row if there is more than one 'x' in each row, and just keep one unique 'x' of that row for each duplicate.

Reproduce

```
dat <- data.frame(one = c("x", "x", "x"), two = c("x", "", "x"), three = c("", "", ""), type = c("chocolate", "vanilla",
                                                                                                                        "strawberry"))
```

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far? If nothing maybe you could provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. Possible also a desired outcome as a `data.frame()`

Comment: Why is the last row not duplicated??

Comment: @EricFail added reproducible df!

Comment: @Onyambu fixed!

Comment: Nice question. Attracted so many different ways of implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using tidyr::gather**

In the same vein as MKR and Anant's solutions.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  mutate(i=row_number())         %>%
  gather("Key", "Val", -type,-i) %>%
  rowid_to_column                %>%
  spread(Key, Val,fill = "")     %>%
  `[`(rowSums(.=="x")>0,)        %>%
  arrange(i)                     %>%
  select(type,one,two,three)

#         type one two three
# 1  chocolate   x          
# 2  chocolate       x      
# 3    vanilla   x          
# 4 strawberry   x          
# 5 strawberry       x
```

Though you'd probably be happy with just that (column `three` would appear if it was filled for at leat one value, but rows are shuffled):

```
dat %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  gather("Key", "Val", -type,na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  rowid_to_column  %>%
  spread(Key, Val,fill = "") %>%
  select(-1)

#          type one two
# 1   chocolate   x    
# 2     vanilla   x    
# 3  strawberry   x    
# 4   chocolate       x
# 5  strawberry       x
```

**Binding dataframes**

Another way splitting the data in different data frames then binding them (looks like what @Acccumulation tried to explain in his answer):

```
dat %>%
  map(1:3,~filter(.y[c(.x,4)],.y[.x]=="x"),.) %>%
  bind_rows                  %>%
  modify(as.character)       %>%
  `[<-`(is.na(.),value="")   %>%
  select(one,two,three,type)     

#   one two three       type
# 1   x            chocolate
# 2   x              vanilla
# 3   x           strawberry
# 4       x        chocolate
# 6       x       strawberry
```

**Using merge**

```
dat %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  bind_rows(.["type"])     %>%
  map(1:3,~.y[c(.x,4)],.)  %>%
  reduce(merge,all=TRUE)   %>%
  `[<-`(is.na(.),value="") %>%
  `[`(rowSums(.=="x")==1,) %>%
  distinct     

#         type one two three
# 1  chocolate   x          
# 2  chocolate       x      
# 3 strawberry   x          
# 4 strawberry       x      
# 5    vanilla   x
```

**Using unnest**

```
dat %>%
  imap_dfc(~{
    i <- match(.y,names(dat))
    if(.y != "type") map(.x,~`[<-`(character(3),i,.x)) else .x}) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  `[`(rowSums(.=="x")==1,) 

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#         type   one   two three
#        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1  chocolate     x            
# 2  chocolate           x      
# 3    vanilla     x            
# 4 strawberry     x            
# 5 strawberry           x
```

**Using unnest with diag**

```
dat %>%
  rowwise %>%
  transmute(type,cols = list(setNames(data.frame(diag(c(one,two,three)=="x")),c('one','two','three')))) %>%
  unnest %>%
  modify_at(2:4, ~c('','x')[.x+1]) %>%
  `[`(rowSums(.=="x")==1,)

#   # A tibble: 5 x 4
#         type   one   two three
#        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1  chocolate     x            
# 2  chocolate           x      
# 3    vanilla     x            
# 4 strawberry     x            
# 5 strawberry           x
```

**EDIT** *to accommodate OP's request in the comments*:

We take the first solution and use a `right_join` to the source data to make sure all rows are there, then replace NAs with empty strings. We also clean up the first lines of the command as we don't need `i` for arranging anymore.

```
dat2 %>%
  gather("Key", "Val", -type)    %>%
  rowid_to_column                %>%
  spread(Key, Val,fill = "")     %>%
  `[`(rowSums(.=="x")>0,)        %>%
  right_join(dat2["type"])       %>%
  `[<-`(is.na(.),value="")       %>%
  select(type,one,two,three)

#         type one two three
# 1  chocolate   x          
# 2  chocolate       x      
# 3    vanilla   x          
# 4 strawberry   x          
# 5 strawberry       x      
# 6   hazelnut
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! So, I went with the tidyr::gather method. But say, I had a row that was completely empty and I didn't want to remove it. where `dat2 <- data.frame(one = c("x", "x", "x", ""), two = c("x", "", "x", ""), three = c("", "", "", ""), type = c("chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry", "hazelnut"))` - how would I adjust the na.rm? Is the best way to do a if function to say if all of them are NA then leave it?

Comment: Yes it's a bit awkward but all my solutions filter the output at some point... I think all other solutions so far do it as well. What you propose could work but what I propose is to use a `right_join`, see my edit at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `dplyr::gather` to accomplish what you need here, here's a quick example where empty strings are converted to NAs:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
     one = c("x", "x", "x"),
     two = c("x", "", "x"),
     three = c("", "", ""),
     type = c("chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry")
 ) %>%
     na_if("") %>%
     gather("number", "value", one:three) %>%
     filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
     mutate(one = ifelse(number == "one", "x", ""),
            two = ifelse(number == "two", "x", ""),
            three = ifelse(number == "three", "x", "")) %>%
     select(one:three, type) %>%
     arrange(type)

 dat
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  one   two   three type      
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 x     ""    ""    chocolate 
2 ""    x     ""    chocolate 
3 x     ""    ""    strawberry
4 ""    x     ""    strawberry
5 x     ""    ""    vanilla
```

Comment: Smart way to compare and mutate. You can match output needed by OP slight change in your mutate logic(using `ifelse`).

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I didn't include that in the first pass. Updated as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be achieved using `gather` and then `spread`. The steps are:

```
#data
df <- read.table(text = "one    two    three    type 
x      x       ''        chocolate
x      ''       ''         vanilla 
x      x       ''        strawberry", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df
#  one two three       type
#1   x   x    NA  chocolate
#2   x        NA    vanilla
#3   x   x    NA strawberry
library(tidyverse)    
df1 <- gather(df, "Key", "Val", -type)

#         type   Key  Val
#1  chocolate 1   one    x
#2    vanilla 2   one    x
#3 strawberry 3   one    x
#4  chocolate 4   two    x
#5    vanilla 5   two     
#6 strawberry 6   two    x
#7  chocolate 7 three <NA>
#8    vanilla 8 three <NA>
#9 strawberry 9 three <NA>

#Make type unique before using sperad
df1$type <- paste(df1$type, 1:nrow(df1))

df2 <- spread(df1, Key, Val)

#Remove the digit part form the column name
df2$type <- gsub("(^\\w+)\\s.+","\\1",df2$type, perl = T)

# filter for the rows where either of one, two or three is 'x'
df_final <- df2 %>% filter(one == "x" | two == "x" | three == "x")

#set blank value to NA cell
df_final[is.na(df_final)] <- ""

df_final
#        type one three two
#1  chocolate   x          
#2  chocolate             x
#3 strawberry   x          
#4 strawberry             x
#5    vanilla   x
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this interesting question.

Here is a solution using base R. The idea is to split the data frame based on the ID of row, count how many `x` in each row, create a matrix with diagonal all equal to 1 with dimension based on the count of `x`, convert the matrix to be a data frame and replace 1 to be `x` and 0 to be "", and manipulate the data frame and then combine them all together.

This solution should work for any numbers of columns with `x`, but it assumes the `type` column is the only column without any thing to do with `x`. If you have more than one column like the `type` columns, you may need to modify the codes for your needs.

```
# Create a row ID
dat$ID <- 1:nrow(dat)

# Split the data frame based on ID
dat_list <- split(dat, f = dat$ID)

dat_list2 <- lapply(dat_list, function(x){
  x$ID <- NULL            # Remove the ID column    
  x_count <- sum(grepl("x", as.vector(unlist(x)))) # Count how many x per row
  m <- diag(x_count)      # Create a matrix with diagnol value to be 1 based on count
  cols <- names(x)[sapply(x, function(x) grepl("x", x))]  # Document the columns with "x"
  cols_n <- names(x)[!(names(x) %in% cols | names(x) %in% "type")]  # Document the columns do not have "x"
  dat <- as.data.frame(m) # Create a data frame by converting the m matrix
  colnames(dat) <- cols   # Assign column names
  dat[dat == 0] <- ""     # Replace 0 with "",
  dat[dat == "1"] <- "x"  # Replace 1 with "x"
  if (length(cols_n) >= 1){
    dat[, cols_n] <- ""     # Add all other columns in addition to type
  }
  dat$type <- x$type      # Add the type column
  return(dat)
})

# Combine all data frame in dat_list2
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, dat_list2)
# Re-assign the row name
rownames(dat2) <- 1:nrow(dat2)

dat2
#   one two three       type
# 1   x            chocolate
# 2       x        chocolate
# 3   x              vanilla
# 4   x           strawberry
# 5       x       strawberry
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[one == "x" & two == "x", id := 1]
df1 <- df[id == 1, ]
df[, two := ""]
df1[, one := ""]
df <- rbind(df, df1)
df[, id := NULL]
df
```

Output:

```
     one two three       type
1:   x        NA  chocolate
2:   x        NA    vanilla
3:   x        NA strawberry
4:       x    NA  chocolate
5:       x    NA strawberry
```

Comment: Will this work easily if I have 7 columns with a multitude of combinations of 'x's within each column?

Comment: No, it won't work. You have more columns in your data?

Comment: In my actual data, I have 7 columns with all kinds of combinations. Sometimes all 7 columns have an 'x' in it in which case I would need 7 different rows with a unique one 'x' in each row, sometimes 5/7 have an 'x' in which case I would need 5 different rows

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using `tidyverse` tools. You will probably need to adjust to include all 7 column names, but hopefully it should still work. The insight is that using `gather`, adding a unique `rowid`, and then using `spread` forces there to still be the same number of rows since each row is now different from the rest (by `type` and `rowid`). The rest is just converting empty characters to `NA` and then removing the extra rows that are all `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tribble(
  ~one, ~two, ~three, ~type,
  "x", "x", "", "chocolate",
  "x", "", "", "vanilla",
  "x", "x", "", "strawberry"
) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(one:three), function(x) ifelse(x == "", NA_character_, x)) %>%
  gather(key = "number", value = "x", one:three) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  spread(key = number, value = x) %>%
  arrange(type) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(one) & is.na(two) & is.na(three))) %>%
  select(one, two, three, type) %>%
  print()
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  one   two   three type      
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 x     NA    NA    chocolate 
2 NA    x     NA    chocolate 
3 x     NA    NA    strawberry
4 NA    x     NA    strawberry
5 x     NA    NA    vanilla
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there'll always be an x before the following x. I.e. if there is an x in `two` there won't be one in `one`. Otherwise I'm not actually sure what you're expecting.

So, assuming your data frame is called `df`, just find the xs in rows `two` and `three` and duplicate them whilst clearing the others.

```
twoMatches <- df$two == 'x'     #Find all the twos with xs
threeMatches <- df$three == 'x' #Find all the threes with xs
df$two[twoMatches] <- ""        #Clear the two field where there were twos
df$three[threeMatches] <- ""    #Clear the three field where there were threes

numTwos <- sum(twoMatches)      #Number of twos
numThrees <- sum(threeMatches)  #Number of threes

#Generate our frame of twos
twoFrame <- data.frame(one = rep("", numTwos), two = rep("x", numTwos), three = rep("", numTwos), type = df[twoMatches, "type"], stringsAsFactors = F)

#Generate our frame of threes
threeFrame <- data.frame(one = rep("", numThrees), two = rep("", numThrees), three = rep("x", numThrees), type = df[threeMatches, "type"], stringsAsFactors = F)

#Bind them all together
outdf <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(df, twoFrame, threeFrame))

#Sort them into something more meaningful
outdf <- outdf[order(outdf$type, outdf$one, outdf$two, outdf$three, decreasing = T),]
```

Output:

[image]